# Merge only some changes from a branch to master

Tags: git, flask

I've been working on an app recently, but I'm kinda new both to web development and git. My app is getting quite big, so it takes about to 2 minutes to load, making testing little changes a bit difficult. Considering that I thought about working with a branch where I load only one view, making my work smoother. There are two important files:

- `index.py`: here, `master` loads all views. This is the file I run when I run the app. In my new branch I modify it so it only loads `relevant_view.py`. When I merge `new_branch` with `master` I'd like to keep master's version.
- `relevant_view.py`: The relevant view. The changes I make here in `new_branch` I want to merge them to `master`.

So, for `master` I want to update it with the `relevant_view.py` changes I made on `new_branch`, but keep `index.py` the way it originally was.

For `new_branch` I would like to keep both changes to `index.py` and `relevant_view.py` I made in that branch.

I'm only  managing to bring both changes to master, which forces me to manually unedit said changes on `index.py`. What would be the way to go? Thanks and please tell me if I'm not explaining myself well. If there's other best practice I'm missing for this kind of issue, please also let me know too.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this

While on branch `new_branch`, run the following:

```sh
git checkout -b new_branch_to_merge
```

This will create a new branch named `new_branch_to_merge` in which the `HEAD` pointer will point to the same commit as the `HEAD` pointer for `new_branch`.

Then, assuming that you haven't added the changes for `relevant_view.py` yet, add and commit them:

```sh
git add relevant_view.py
git commit -m "adding changes to relevant_view.py"
```

Then, you could use `git stash push` to hide the changes to `index.py`

```sh
git stash push
```

Then, merge `new_branch_to_merge` to `master`

```sh
git checkout master
git merge new_branch_to_merge
```

Now, your `master` branch is ahead of `new_branch` by one commit.  To resolve this, run the following commands to ensure that the `HEAD` value of the `new_branch` points to the same commit as that for `master`

```sh
git checkout new_branch
git merge --ff-only master
```

Then, to add the changes to `index.py` to the working directory on `new_branch`, run the following:

```
git stash pop
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I had not seen you answer. When I can make a little time I'll try your answer. Was more complex than I thought !

Comment: @JuanC thanks for the feedback!  Let me know if it helps.